# Solve this system of coupled non-linear equations

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have the following two equations with complex $\alpha, \beta$:
$$0 = -i \omega_m \beta - ig|\alpha|^2 - \frac{\gamma}{2}\beta$$
$$0 = \alpha(i\Delta - \frac{\kappa}{2}) - i\epsilon - ig\alpha(\beta + \beta^*)$$
The other parameters $g, \omega_m, \Delta, \kappa, \gamma, \epsilon$ are real.

To solve this system for $\alpha$, I solved the first equation for $\beta$ and got
$$\beta = \frac{g|\alpha|^2}{\frac{i\gamma}{2} - \omega_m}$$

I then inserted this into the second line and obtained
$$\alpha\left(i\Delta - \frac{\kappa}{2} + \frac{2ig^2\omega_m|\alpha|^2}{\frac{\gamma^2}{4} + \omega_m}\right) = i\epsilon$$However, in this equation, both $\alpha$ and $|\alpha|^2$ appear, and I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

The last equation is of the form $\,\alpha\left(u + i\left(v + w\, |\alpha|^2\right)\right) = i \epsilon\,$ with $\,u,v,w,\epsilon \in \mathbb R\,$.

Taking squared magnitudes on both sides:

$$
|\alpha|^2\left(u^2 + \left(v+ w\,|\alpha|^2\right)^2\right) = \epsilon^2
$$

This is a [cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) equation with real coefficients in $\,|\alpha|^2\,$ which can be solved either algebraically or numerically. Substituting the positive real solution(s) $\,|\alpha|^2\,$ in the first equation of the system gives $\,\beta\,$, then substituting the respective $\,\beta\,$ in the second equation gives $\,\alpha\,$.

Comment: Thanks. Solving this with Mathematica yields some messy and lengthy expressions. Does there even exist an analytic expression?

Comment: @LionCereals The cubic is solvable by radicals, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula) for example. There are also [trigonometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots) and [hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root) forms, depending on the nature of the roots. That said, the calculations can be laborious.